# Changing Excel Cell colours once a word/value in another cell is entered/changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I currently have a spreadsheet with a list of deadline dates in *row C* and status updates in *row E*.

I need the cells in *row C* change to **green** once the words  `Complete`/ `Completed` is written in any of the cells in *Row E*.

There are currently two other rules applied to *Row C* to allow them to change `red` / `yellow` when the dates are approaching or passed so the rule for *Row E* would need to override this.

I have tried to apply a `'Specific Text'` 'containing' `'Complete'` code through conditioning formatting -> highlighting cells -> containing tab which allows that particular cell to change to green, however I need the deadline date cell in the same row to also change to the same colour!

Just in case you need them - Rules for *Row C* are:

=TODAY()+7

=TODAY()

Comment: Use a **formula** for conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand @SalvoF's comment: you need to use a formula for your conditional format.

1. Select your whole table (probably selecting by columns is best).
2. **Conditional Formatting** -> **New Rule**.
3. Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
4. Enter the formula `=$E1="Complete"`. The `$` means that it always looks at column E to figure out whether the formula is true or not.
5. Choose your format.

Note that you could use other formula in the box, like `INSTR`, to determine whether a string matches.

[image]